# Fetching and loading data from zustand

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios, loading, zustand

I'm using: React, Laravel, Zustand,

I'm trying to fetch data from [zustand](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zustand) and load it into React, but I'm still receiving some problems. Now data are fetched successfully, but they are not displayed the first time I visited a page. I need to go back, then again open the page, and the data are loaded. Is there some way how to wait for the data to be loaded? Or I am fetching and loading data the wrong way and there is some other better method?

Zustand:

```
test: null,
  fetchUserPermissionss: async (userId) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(/****/****/${userId});
      const  test  = await response.data;
      set ({test: test});
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  },
```

Component:

```
   const {
    fetchUserPermissionss,
    test
  } = usePermissionsStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDistricts(),
      fetchUserTypes(),
      fetchRoles(),
      fetchPermissions(),
      fetchRolesPermissions()

    if (mode === "edit" && id) {
      const loadData = async () => {

        await getUser(id);
        await fetchUserPermissionss(id);

       const districtsData = [...new Set(**test**.map((item) => item.district_id))];

....
        }
      };
      loadData();
    }
  }, [id, mode]);
```

Thanks for any help!

I try to use

```
 if (isLoading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }
```

Or

```
 !test ?
    <Spinner />
    : ...
```

But this not works at it should.

Comment: It will be nice, if you can reproduce the error with a simple example in codesandbox.io. So that, we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

put fetchUserPermissionss in the useEffect dependency array as well

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).